# securing few sql server database on client deployment

Tags: sql-server, deployment, setup-deployment, web-deployment

here is a debatable question which i want to achieve not sure how .

i am supposed to deliver an asp.net application which has to be installed on client system.i can obfuscate my code and hence protect it . but in case the database is opened by any administrator. the person would be able to see all the entire data which has been given to database .

we do not want the client to control the database anyway even if he has the access to the database for some specific static table . and deny any changes made to those particular tables say  **Table A,Table B** and **Table C**...

how do i track or avoid any changes those are being made to those three tables . and deny them from changing that . is there any possible way for it ? to deny any changes to those tables and control them via private key/public key sort of thing or else some lock mechanism which wd deny any update statements to that table even via administrator having update rights . cause we dont have the control for the database . its the client who would be controlling it .

so how to protect this database in case of any client deployment of a web application database

or else kind of deployment suggestions are most welcome. since we are novice in this application deployment .

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev since they are asking for an application which can be run on web. but at the same time they want it to host of their own . in that way i can protect my code . but not the database. he said he wd be reserving all rights  for that . i agreed upon on condition that the code copyright would be ours . but the usability  license would be their's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general your better option of protecting your code and data that is property of your application would be to do it through a license agreement of sorts. SQL Server offers methods to protect data from unauthorized users but administrators and local admin accounts will be able to get to it if they want too.

You might consider SQL Server compact edition ( http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) 
 I believe it acts more like an embedded database so there is not direct access outside of your application.

Comment: how much Data can a sql server compact edition contain ? does it work with asp.net ? and is it possible to see the compact edition data ? from outside? or the table structure ?

Comment: Added link to compact edition page. I know as far as user sees it will just be a file on the server. It does support ASP and how you see the data I am not sure of.

Comment: but i guess Entity framework or Nhibernate community doesnt support sql server compact edition well ? this is a bit off topic . but still asking .. and how abt sql lite over sql server compact edition ?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a very bad idea.

If it has to be an ASP.NET application then I would suggest that you deploy it on a server that you can set access privileges to. That way no one will be able to access the code nor the application. That's what the purpose of web applications is for in the first place.

Comment: Definitely I know its a very bad idea . but look above in my comments for Sergei . i have answered why i need to do that . in a manner i m in a fix . so that's why i am here . so that how to proceed into this Problem with a solution . i definitely don't deny that this is going to be very stupid .. but to the solution if you have any other alternative . so i m asking for that :)